# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in solr, but heap is not full

Tags: java, solr, heap-memory

Premise: I'm a newbye on java questions, but I'm trying to understand.

I'm experiencing "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" in a SOLR instance under high load (many concurrent requests in read only).

I've found that the general solution in these situations is to increase maximum heap size with `-Xmx` parameter, but looking at figures on jconsole I'm observing that only 50% of 1G total heap is used. Only Eden space and Survivor space have sometimes reached 100%, but I've understood this is normal.

Are there cases in which we can have OutofMemoryError in heap space even if it isn't full? Which parameters can I set to avoid this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not permgen area that is getting filled?

Comment: Yes, solr log says:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: @AniketThakur you will get permgen error if  permgen area that is getting filled not heap error

Comment: ok then it's the heap only that is getting filled. yes when eden space is filled it's content is transferred to one of the survivor space along with content of other survivor space. And only after full GC content of YG are moved to OG.

Comment: i would suggest take a heap dump from jconsole or jvisualvm to see actual heap usage.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if you using JREx32 on OSx64. It can cause your problem.
I just now up my solr server after viewing logs.

See on a java dump log on something like this:

> tenured generation   total 174784K, used 174765K [0x09750000,
>   0x14200000, 0x14200000)    the space 174784K,  99% used [0x09750000,
>   0x141fb588, 0x141fb600, 0x14200000)

It seems that Garbage Collector is working not so good for somths java generations in different bit of JRE and OS.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible.  A somewhat common case is if you have really large objects, then sometimes the JVM will automatically instantiate them in tenured generation.  If there isn't a contiguous block available to instantiate it in then you'll get the heap space error.

I hit a similar problem with Solr about a year ago, and it was related to the heavy use of dynamic fields in the import, which were in turn trying to create many (and large) objects.  Do you use a lot of dynamic fields?

I think the commenters have it right, you should take a heap dump and try to figure out what is going on that way.  When you get to Solr tuning you'll likely be tweaking the heap space sizes anyway.

I found this page pretty useful: http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.outOfMemory

Comment: Great link @Mike: very interesting. We don't use dynamic fields. I've executed a heap dump but now I'm trying to understand it: it's huge!

Comment: This is not an answer rather than a comment.